# Adding a search box to the homepage of a website built on Sylius

Tags: symfony, search, composer-php, e-commerce, sylius

Could someone please explain how I can add a search box to the homepage of my website built on Sylius?

I have tried using the SyliusSearchBundle but that seems to be very out of data and the sample config settings throw errors.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**
Steps below work at the time I'm writing. SyliusElasticSearchBundle plugin is in a heavy development state, some of the things crash now, but will be fixed for sure.

I've created a demo repository here: https://github.com/mheki/sylius-search-demo

You need running ElasticSearch and a SyliusElasticSearchBundle plugin.

Follow installation instructions from readme: https://github.com/Lakion/SyliusElasticSearchBundle

Just bear in mind to install sylius dev-master (circular dependency...)

Import bundle's config, routing, enable it in AppKernel.

**At the moment I'm writing the bundle needed `filter_sets` config, otherwise it crashed**

So start with the simple search by product name:

```
lakion_sylius_elastic_search:
    filter_sets:
        default:
            filters:
                name: 
                    type: string
```

Populate elastic index with:

```
bin/console fos:elastic:pop
```

Override original routing for `lakion_elastic_search_shop_product_index` - use `filter_set:` for your channel code.

```
lakion_elastic_search_shop_product_index:
    path: /products
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
         _controller: lakion_sylius_elastic_search.controller.search:filterAction
         _sylius:
            template: "@LakionSyliusElasticSearch/Product/index.html.twig"
            resource_class: "%sylius.model.product.class%"
            filter_set: default
    requirements:
        slug: .+
```

Original product index page was failing for me and I had to remove

```
{{ form_row(form.search) }}
```

from it. So copied `@LakionSyliusElasticSearch/Product/index.html.twig` into `Resources` directory:
`Resources\LakionSyliusElasticSearchBundle\views\Product\index.html.twig` and made that change.

Now the last thing is to create a form, for example copying the file `_security.html.twig` from SyliusShopBundle. Add something like this:

```
<div class="item">
        <form action="{{ path('lakion_elastic_search_shop_product_index') }}" method="get">
            <div class="ui icon input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'sylius.ui.search'|trans }}..." name="filter_set[name]" />
                <button type="submit" class="ui button mini">
                    <i class="search icon"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

and here we go :)

[image: search on demo shop]

Comment: ,I have tried to implement the search box as you have explained, but when I search for a product, it show all the products and not the particular product I have search in the search box.

Comment: Thanks, I realised ProductPriceRange worked out of the box, but for product name match you have to add a little bit more code. Please have a look at: https://github.com/mheki/sylius-search-demo/commit/8fb6a98 where I basically copied SearchController from Lakion bundle and used SearchType form type.

Comment: Thanks It works nicely. Now I will try to make it autocomplete with ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the SyliusElasticSearchBundle plugin, you can implement a simple search on your own (which search inside the product name, description and category name) :

Create a classic html search form, for example:

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="{{path('app_search_results') }}">
    <input type="search" id="site-search" name="q"
           placeholder="{{ 'walrus.search.input.placeholder'|trans }}"
           aria-label="{{ 'walrus.search.aria.label'|trans }}">
    <button>{{ 'walrus.search.aria.button'|trans }}</button>
</form>
```

Create a controller action for the route 'app_search_results' in order to get the search request sent by your search form :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sylius\Component\Channel\Context\ChannelContextInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Locale\Context\LocaleContextInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Resource\Repository\RepositoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @var LocaleContextInterface
 */
private $locale;
/**
 * @var ChannelContextInterface
 */
private $channelContext;
/**
 * @var RepositoryInterface
 */
private $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    LocaleContextInterface $locale,
    ChannelContextInterface $channelContext,
    RepositoryInterface $productRepository
)
{
    $this->locale = $locale;
    $this->channelContext = $channelContext;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

/**
 * @Route("/search", name="app_search_results")
 */
public function searchAction(Request $request) : Response
{

    $searchTerm = $request->query->get('q');

    $channel = $this->channelContext->getChannel();
    $localeCode = $this->locale->getLocaleCode();

    $products = $this->productRepository->findByTerm($channel, $localeCode, $searchTerm);


    return $this->render(
        '@App/search/searchListProducts.html.twig',
        [
            'products' => $products
        ]
    );
}

}
```

*Don't forget to manually wire the dependency injected through the constructor.*

Override the product repository in order to implements the findByTerm() method :

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\ORM\ProductRepository as 
BaseProductRepository;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ChannelInterface;


class ProductRepository extends BaseProductRepository
{

public function findByTerm(ChannelInterface $channel, string $locale, $searchTerm): array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->addSelect('translation')
                // get the translated product for the product regarding the current locale
                ->innerJoin('p.translations', 'translation', 'WITH', 'translation.locale = :locale')
                ->orWhere('translation.name LIKE :searchTerm')
                ->orWhere('translation.description LIKE :searchTerm')
                // get the taxons of the product
                ->innerJoin('p.productTaxons', 'productTaxon')
                ->innerJoin('productTaxon.taxon', 'taxon')
                // get the translated taxon
                ->innerJoin('taxon.translations', 'taxonTranslation', 'WITH', 'taxonTranslation.locale = :locale')
                ->orWhere('taxonTranslation.name LIKE :searchTerm')

                ->andWhere(':channel MEMBER OF p.channels')
                ->andWhere('p.enabled = true')
                ->setParameter('searchTerm', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
                ->setParameter('locale', $locale)
                ->setParameter('channel', $channel)
                ->getQuery();

    return $qb->getResult();

}

}
```

You just need now to create the page rendering the list of product (the @App/search/searchListProducts.html.twig). And to tell Sylius to use your custom HomepageController instead of the original one. Same goes for your Product Repository. This can be done inside the services.yml file of you app folder :

```
services:
    sylius.controller.shop.homepage:
        public: true
        class: AppBundle\Controller\Shop\HomepageController
        arguments:
            - '@templating'
            - '@sylius.context.locale'
            - '@sylius.repository.taxon'

sylius_product:
    resources:
        product:
            classes:
                repository: AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
```